# Observer design pattern using boost asio concurrent channel

Tags: c++, design-patterns, boost, boost-asio, coroutine

My program blocks when trying to send data from producer to consumer using boost asio channel.

The async_send method is not asynchronous. And the documentation says :this method send asynchronously data.

I tried to implement the observer design pattern using boost asio channels to send data between threads.

But Im a little bit surprised for the behaviour of async_send.

```
struct Subject
{
    using Channel = asio::experimental::concurrent_channel<void(
        std::error_code, std::shared_ptr<Response>)>;
    std::list<Channel> channels;
};
asio::awaitable<void> for_each_channel(Subject& subject, auto action)
{
    for(auto it = subject.channels.begin();
        it != subject.channels.end();)
    {
        if(it->is_open())
        {
            co_await action(*it);
            ++it;
        } else
        {
            it = subject.channels.erase(it);
        }
    }
}
asio::awaitable<void> notify_all(
    Subject& subject, std::shared_ptr<Response> response)
{
    co_await for_each_channel(
        subject,
        [&](Subject::Channel& channel)
        {
            return channel.async_send(
                std::error_code{},
                response,
                asio::use_awaitable); // blocks here
        });
}
asio::awaitable<void> close(Subject& subject)
{
    co_await for_each_channel(
        subject,
        [&](Subject::Channel& channel)
        {
            return channel.async_send(
                std::error_code{asio::error::operation_aborted},
                nullptr,
                asio::use_awaitable);
        });
}
auto& add_observer(Subject& subject, auto executor)
{
    return subject.channels.emplace_back(executor);
}
void remove_observer(Subject::Channel& observer)
{
    observer.close();
}
asio::awaitable<void> producer(Subject& subject)
{
    for(;;)
    {
        auto data = std::make_shared<Response>();
        co_await notify_all(subject, std::move(data));
    }
    co_await close(subject);
}
asio::awaitable<void> consumer(Subject& subject)
{
    bool ok{true};
    auto& observer =
        add_observer(subject, co_await asio::this_coro::executor);
    while(ok)
    {
        auto const [ec, response] = co_await observer.async_receive(
            asio::as_tuple(asio::use_awaitable));
        if(ec)
        {
            break;
        }
        co_await treatment(); // treat the response
    }
```

My question is why async_send is not asynchronous.

How to avoid blocking the producer threads ?

Is there a more useful/helpful documentation for boost asio channels other than boost documentation.

Comment: Why is every second line empty?

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: I had a large answer typed up, but I lost it due to browser forgetting the draft. I found some of the code I had been testing with https://godbolt.org/z/WbGT9hnxe. Note that there is an unexplained diagnostic with ASan/UBSan - which is why I didn't post it earlier. There are important changes to the code that fixed thread-safety and lifetime issues. I might find time to write it again from scratch if you are interested

Comment: @sehe thank you very much for your reply. It's very helpful. I'm wandering if you have any website where you share your work, ideas, tips and best practices.

Comment: @Peter To date, I think that site is stackoverflow.com.

Comment: @sehe, did you had time to make this sample available in boost asio example folder. I think it's more interesting than the proxy example

Comment: @Peter You could consider submitting it yourself. To be honest I think the proxy example is cleaner and technically more interesting.

Comment: @sehe, thank you for your reply, I will work on it

Comment: @sehe, I think that the reported warnings are false positive because I don't see any issue with them. Clang 16 does not report any warning with fsanitize thread, address and undefined so the issue is in gcc.

Comment: There might be an issue with gcc*, FTFY. Good to know. I might post as an answer then, anyways. I'll have look at what I had again to see whether it makes sense :)

Comment: Yes, it will be very helpful for people wanting to use this experimental feature in boost asio !

Comment: @sehe, the main purpose of a concurrent channel is to be used imby differentthreads ? When the producer and consumer are in separate threads, is there a risk of a race condition occurring on the subs_ variable within the Subject?

Comment: @Peter I *very subtly* (or not) made sure of that by copying the `list<>` instead of taking the reference.

Comment: Using this https://godbolt.org/z/zf4nvb4Ed (i.e. running the context inside two threads) gcc and clang report data race warnings

Comment: @sehe,I added mutex before each use of subs_, seems ok but there is also heap-use-after-free

Comment: You cannot really put a mutex "before" something (they're called _critical sections_ (or old-fashioned Monitor) for a reason). Besides, the code was _literally_ single-threaded so mutual exclusion locks buy you nothing.

Comment: subs_ was not thread safe so I copie it safely to avoid concurrent read write. Callbacks are called without holding the mutex. Otherwise, how to achieve safety on the observer pattern

Answer (score 0):

Just a hunch here, but...

You're using coroutines with `asio::awaitable<void>` (very cool). But your lambda does a `return async_send(... use_awaitable)` and the compiler might not realize that lambda needs to be more like `asio::awaitable<void>` than a standard function.

Try `co_return async_send(...` within that lambda instead. ([co_return](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/co_return))